# Serilog Email sink

Tags: email, mandrill, serilog

I'm trying to send emails using Serilog.Sinks.Email NuGet package (v1.5.0.0) with the Mandrill SMTP service. The following code executes but does not send any emails. When I try and use the same credentials using the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, it works and send an email.

```
EmailConnectionInfo info = new EmailConnectionInfo()
{
    EmailSubject = "Email subject",
    FromEmail = "from@gmail.com",
    MailServer = "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("mandrill_username", "mandrill_apikey"),
    Port = 587,
    ToEmail = "to@gmail.com"
};

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Email(info)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Error("Houston we have a problem");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you spotted, this was a bug in the latest build of the Email sink, which your graciously-provided pull request has fixed. Version [1.5.13](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Email/1.5.13) of the sink, now on NuGet, includes the fix.